# How to capture a photo automatically in iPhone and iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cordova, ipad

[How to capture photo automatically in android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228607/how-to-capture-photo-automatically-in-android-phone) is about how to take a picture automatically without people's interaction. This feature is needed in many applications. For example, when you are going to take a picture of a document, you expect that the camera can take it automatically when the full document is insider the picture (or four corners of the document). So my question is how about doing it in iPhone or iPad?

Recently, I am working on [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), and does someone know that there are some plugins that have already existed for this kind of camera operations? Thanks

EDIT:
This operation will be done in an APP that will be given the full access of the camera, and the task is how to develop such an APP.

Comment: It is not possible to open the camera without the user interaction. The user has to give permission to your app to use the camera for the first time!

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Thanks, and I assume the app is running and it has the full permission to access the camera.

Comment: You cannot set the permission through code. When you access the camera, a popup appears and user has to click Allow to give permission!

Comment: @Teja Nandamuri thanks, and I assume that this app is not used for the first time.

Comment: then u should use avfoundation framework to capture the image!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of capturing photo, you should capture video frames. When the captured frame satisfies your requirements, stop capturing the video and proceed.